# Incrementing an IntegerField in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement the Polls app like the one in the Django documentation.
I have an IntegerField to represent the number of votes an option has in my Polls app but if I try to add the voter to the list of voters and increment it by one in my `views.py` ever time a user votes, it adds to the user to the list of voters but the vote count doesn't increase.
This is my Choice model...

```
votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
voters = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name="my_votes")
```

This is my vote function in `views.py`

```
option.votes += 1
user = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user)
option.voters.add(user)
```

How do i fix this please?

Comment: You need to call`save()` method as `option.save()`

Comment: It worked. It completely didn’t occur to me that I was missing that line. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you're not saving the changes that you're making to the "option" object after updating its vote count. Make sure you call the "save" method on the "option" object after incrementing the vote count:

Here is a sample code for it:

```
option.votes += 1
user = UserProfile.objects.get(user = request.user)
option.voters.add(user) 
option.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I completely forgot

Answer (score 0):

Please *don't* store the number of votes together with the voters. Keeping two fields in sync is a lot harder than one might expect. It means that when you delete a vote, you need to ensure that the number of votes decreases, when a user removes their accounts, you have to decrease the number as well. While this all looks very simple, it is easy to forget certain use cases.

Typically you store the voters, for example with a reference to the corresponding `User` model:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Choice(models.Model):
    # …
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='my_votes'
    )
```

Then in the view you add the logged in user to the choice:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST


@login_required
def vote_for_choice(request, choice_pk):
    choice = get_object_or_404(Choice, pk=choice_pk)
    choice.voters.add(request.user)
    return redirect('name-of-some-view')
```

Finally if we want to know the number of votes for each choice, it is sufficient to [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Choice.objects.annotate(votes=Count('voters'))
```

The `Choice` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.votes` that contains the number of related `voters`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. I’ll effect the necessary changes.